# C# Relatioships between same type objects without db

Tags: c#, relationship

I get a list of 90 products via xml serialization, within each product one of the varibles is CO2 emitions which can be 0,1, or 2. People can pick up too 12 of the products one at a time. Depending on the product picked and the ones already in their list the CO2 for each could change. So I need to set up three types of relationships between all 90 products. Which could be a positive relationship, Negitive, or Neutral. If a second product is added that has a Positive relationship with the first than depending on its current CO2 level for example would go from 1 to 2. The third added would have an affect on the first two and so on. How do I set up 90 products with relationships than are changeable in the future without a DB.

Update...
Below I need to specific relationships between Product points for all 90 products that effect each other as their added to a list.

```
[DataContract(Name = "Product", Namespace = "")]
public class Product
{
    private List<ProductTypes> productTypes = new List<ProductTypes>();

    [DataMember(Name = "ProductName", IsRequired = true, Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ProductTypes", IsRequired = true, Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<ProductTypes> ProductTypes { get { return productTypes; } set { productTypes = value; } }
}
```

TYPES

```
[DataContract(Name = "ProductTypes", Namespace = "")]
public class ProductTypes
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ProductNumber", IsRequired = true, Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public long ProductNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ProductRegion", IsRequired = true, Order = 3, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ProductRegion { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ProductType", IsRequired = true, Order = 4, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ProductColor", IsRequired = true, Order = 5, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ProductColor { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ProductPoints", IsRequired = true, Order = 6, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int ProductPoints { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem but as @HimBromBeere said more details would be helpful

Comment: updated........

Comment: @J.Boehm Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the page [ask] because it is not clear what you are asking. Please edit your post to include a specific question, preferable with the source code you have tried to solve your problem but which doesn't work (and explain how it doesn't work).